# Highcharts stacked percentage area

Tags: python, sqlite, highcharts

I have different series of data with actual and expected value. For each country it's expected that there's to be done at least xx assignments depending on the team size. The expected value can increase or decrease. New data is retrieved every day and saved in a sqlite database. The idea is to present data using FLASK in Python.

The sqlite database has the following layout: [Data layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/362Fw.png)

I am dreaming of plotting these data in such way that it's shown in percentage wise. Let's say if I were to see the plot for Greece only, it would then look at the maximum expected value, in this case 12, and would only plot 58% of the area since the maximum covered value is 7. If I were to also see the plot for Poland, the expected value would then be 22, which means in order to reach 100% both countries have to complete their assignments. 
I have tried, but I am kind of lost. Here is my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'area'
},
title: {
    text: 'Covered assignents by country'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    title: {
        enabled: false
    }
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Percent'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} assignments)<br/>',
    split: true
},
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        stacking: 'percent',
        lineColor: '#ffffff',
        lineWidth: 1,
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#ffffff'
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Greece',
    data: [{x: Date.UTC(2017,09,08), y:4}, {x: Date.UTC(2017,09,09), y:6}, {x: Date.UTC(2017,09,10), y:7}]
}, {
    name: 'Poland',
    data: [{x: Date.UTC(2017,09,08), y:1}, {x: Date.UTC(2017,09,09), y:3}, {x: Date.UTC(2017,09,10), y:5}]
}, {
    name: 'Italy',
    data: [{x: Date.UTC(2017,09,08), y:1}, {x: Date.UTC(2017,09,09), y:2}, {x: Date.UTC(2017,09,10), y:7}]
}]
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ehnhq0pz/3/

I hope it makes sense :)

Comment: How about adding en extra series, with the missing values for assignments? That extra series could be disabled for a user (hidden in legend, transparent colors, disabled tooltip etc.), something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ehnhq0pz/6/ Note: it's not the summary of all "expected" values, but `all_expected_values - all_covered_values`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `stacking` from **"percent"** to **"normal"** ("percent" always fills the chart to the top). Then you need to calculate the `y` values as percentages before you make the data series:

```
data: [{x: Date.UTC(2017,09,08), origTasks:4, y:14}, ...
```

Above, **14** is the percentage you somehow calculate yourself. Note that you can include other data in the series as well, and later access it in tooltips for example (here: `origTasks`).

http://jsfiddle.net/ehnhq0pz/5/

Comment: I noticed that the percentage stays the same when you filter the series. Seems like it's not updating the overall assigments?